# Integrating AWS device farm with Jenkins

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I want to integrate my Jenkins build with AWS device farm. So, while creating a project on AWS device farm, it asks to upload the apk to test. I want that the apk should be picked from Jenkins server location and I don't have to manually upload apk to AWS device farm.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Project in AWS device farm is mandatory to upload an APK to proceed with the project creation.

The same will happen with the device pool, you can create a device pool only after creating a Run.

After you create that all this information will be available in Jenkins Server (of course after Authentication and plug in installed)

Another was is using AWS CLI but I can't give you more information as I haven't used yet

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure Jenkins to upload your compiled application to AWS Device Farm. Install the [AWS Device Farm Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWS+Device+Farm+Plugin) and set `Application` to `**/app-debug-unaligned.apk`.

You can also watch our [Jenkins integration webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmEeO_fUkp8) for more information.

Comment: Impressive stuff. These hidden gems should be in your documentation, so we don't have to write whole script to run jenkins job :)

Comment: @python how do we get it to work in jenkinsfile with a custom env and test spec